# Bootstrap navbar-inverse

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I believe I am correctly linking to the bootstrap scripts and stylesheets, but `.navbar-inverse` and `.bg-inverse` don't seem to work as I expect by making the Navbar background dark. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>My Coffee</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
    
    
    
    
    </body>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you provide the code snippet with the style.css file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Bootstrap beta version. Use the Alpha version. It will solve the problem. This is commented code from bootstrap site.

- Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.6 (https://getbootstrap.com)
- Copyright 2011-2017 The Bootstrap Authors
- Copyright 2011-2017 Twitter, Inc.
- Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)

Comment: I did that I copied the links of the alpha version, it changed the colors but now a new problem arises. it is showing all contents of navbar i.e Home, Link, Disabled in toggle bar even page is opened in a laptop. Beta version is the latest why it is not working for a beta.

Comment: I think you need to find a stable version of bootstrap. Alpha-Beta versions are unstable.